# How to change mouse click to mouse hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseover

Here is the [**jsfiddle link**](https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/Ld3x24a6/1/) in which I got the code for the animated tooltips, but the problem is that on `click` only they are working, I want that to be animate when I `hover` the mouse on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/d0j0pjno/1/).

Use mouse events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

```
$('.popover-example li a').mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).trigger("click");
}).mouseleave(function() {
   $(this).trigger("click");
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this:

```
$('.popover-example a').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).click();
  }
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/14Lz0f5z/